# Give an explicit example of a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathcal{F}_1$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $\Omega = \{(i, j)|i, j \in \{-1, 1\}\}$. 
The first part of the question is to give an example of two event spaces $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ of subsets of $\Omega$, such that $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2$ is also an event space. For this I have $\mathcal{F}_1 = \{(-1, -1), \Omega, \emptyset, \{(-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)\} \}$ and $\mathcal{F}_2 = \{\{(1, 1), (1, -1)\}, \Omega, \emptyset, \{(-1, 1), (-1, -1)\} \}$, and this works because the complement of $\{(-1, -1)\} \cup \{(1, 1), (1, -1)\}$ is not contained in $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2$. My definition of an event space has been included below.

The second part of the question is as follows:
give an explicit example of a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathcal{F}_1$. How would I go about answering this? My definition of a probability measure has been included below.

Event space definition: 
let $\Omega$ be the sample space and $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of subsets of $\Omega$. $\mathcal{F}$ is an *event space* (also called $\sigma$-*algebra*) if it satisfies 
(*i*) $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$; (*ii*) if $A \subseteq \Omega, A \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow A^c \in \mathcal{F}$ ($\mathcal{F}$ is closed under complements); (*iii*) if {$A_n: n \in \mathbb{N}$} is such that $A_n \in \mathcal{F} \ \forall n$ then $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathcal{F}$$ ($\mathcal{F}$ is closed under countable unions.)

Probability measure definition: 
given a sample space $\Omega$ and an event space $\mathcal{F}$, a function $\mathbb{P}: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called a *probability measure* if it satisfies 
(*i*) $\mathbb{P}(B) \in [0, 1]$ for every $B \in \mathcal{F}$; (*ii*) $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$; (*iii*) (Countable additivity) For every $A_n \in \mathcal{F}, n \ge 1$ disjoint events (i.e. for all $m, n \geq$ such that $m \neq n, A_m \cap A_n = \emptyset$, $$\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n) $$

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the event space $\mathcal{F}_1$ can be rewritten as $\mathcal{F}_1 = \{\Omega, \emptyset, A, A^c\}$, where $A = (-1, -1)$. Thus, in order to get a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathcal{F}_1$, we assign as follows
$$
    \mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1, \mathbb{P}(\emptyset) =0, \mathbb{P}(A) = p, \mathbb{P}(A^c) = 1-p
$$
for some $p \in [0, 1]$. Can you check if $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure ?

Comment: I guess I just have to check $\mathbb{P}$ against the definition of a probability measure to check if $\mathbb{P}$ is really a probability measure?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @Alex

Comment: What about countable additivity. How do we verify this characteristic is satisfied for the probability measure? @Thành Nguyễn